# Combining reflection, enums and generics in Kotlin, type inference fails, but I don't know it as well

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, enums

I'm using reflection to load an Enum class I'm using to integrate with an existing Java application.
In Java this is written as (in a class ValueUtil):

```
static <E extends Enum<E>> Class<E> getEnumType(String typeAsString) { ..reflection stuff.. }
```

In Kotlin I try to use the result of this method.

```
private fun createEnumParameter(type: String, value: String, id: String?): EnumParameter<*> {
    val clazz = getEnumType(type)
    return createParam(clazz, value, id)
}

private fun <E: Enum<E>> getEnumType(type: String): Class<E> {
    return ValueParseUtil.getEnumType<E>(type)
}

private fun createParam(...): ... { ... }
```

However, the compiler states:
[Type inference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3yqF.png)

So I try as best as I can to specify what I know (Enum<*>):
[Enum<*> error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd4yf.png)

This fails due to enum recursion in the generics (which I/Kotlin/Java need(s) by the way).

Is reflection + enums + generics a recipe for compiler errors?

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When concrete recursive generic type is unknown, you can emulate raw types by suppressing this error:

```
@Suppress("UPPER_BOUND_VIOLATED")
val clazz = getEnumType<Enum<*>>(type)
```

Comment: Thanks. Lateron I also used Enum.valueOf which obviously will break since Enum<*> is not specific enough, but there is a way around this: clazz.enumConstants